# Python - micro:bit add a variable in a function

Tags: python, bbc-microbit

I am trying to add a variable 'ch' for a radio function in microbit, but always I compile I receive an error message.

The idea is send any argument to ch to be incorporate in the radio config function.

```
from microbit import *
import radio
radio.on()
#-----------
# This channel can vary due to an external input
ch = 30
radio.config(channel=ch) # the original syntaxes is: radio.config(channel=7)

#-------------------
```

Appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: I don't think the error is coming from the code you posted, can you post the line that is throwing the error?

Comment: Why do you use `%ch`

Comment: import radio
    from microbit import *
        radio.on()
    while True:
        if button_a.was_pressed():
            ch = 19
    
        if button_b.was_pressed():
            ch = 20
    
        radio.config(channel=%ch)
        incoming = radio.receive()
        if incoming == 'teste':
        display.scroll("Channel"%ch)

Comment: Sorry it´s my first time here I can´t put in a code format.
I have used %ch, just for try.
I have also let as ch, only, but no success as well.
In other languages, like vba, vb I know that is possible to combines variable into functions but I have not idea about Python.
The problem I see is that the microbit argument is "radio.config(channel =7" - so I can´t find a way to break the function, removing the 7 and put a variable and the function still be valid

Comment: By the way, thanks...

Comment: I could make it doing this:                  radio.config(channel=(ch)) Thanks

Comment: I think your issue was trying to use `radio.config(channel=%ch)`

Answer (score 1):

Your error isn't coming from the `radio.config(channel=ch)` line
it's `display.scroll("channel" % ch)` should read `display.scroll("channel %d" % ch)`